# What are the infinite-dimensional unitary irreps of the little group for a massless particle, ISO(2)?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Wigner's classification implies that the internal state of a massless particle transforms under an irreducible unitary representation of ISO(2), the group of isometries on the plane. Since ISO(2) is a semidirect product group of 2d translations and 1d rotations, we can construct representations that don't transform under the translation part, which yields the standard helicity representations that classify all massless bosons that we see in the standard model.

I am curious about more general the more general continuous-spin unitary representations of ISO(2) which transform nontrivially under the translation part of the group. Because the group of translations is noncompact these representations will generally be infinite-dimensional, and thus look like subspaces of functions on the plane transforming via composition with the group elements. Presumably one may also construct more complex representations by taking tensor products of these representations and then removing nontrivial invariant subspaces, as one does in finite-dimensional cases. These representations are unitary with respect to the standard inner product on functions. However, while this naive construction will produce a unitary representation, it will not yield an *irreducible* representation: for instance, the subspace of harmonic functions $\nabla^2 f(x,y) = 0$ on the plane is invariant under the action of the Euclidean group.

My question is-- what are the *irreducible* infinite-dimensional representations of ISO(2)?